# Install plugin with wp-cli in a CI environment

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache, wp-cli

I'm trying to install the [w3-total-cache plugin](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) in a wordpress docker image with the `wp-cli`, but it seems to try to connect to the database, even tough I don't try to activate it. In the Dockerfile I install other themes/plugins with composer and everything seems fine, but the only package I found for the `w3tc` plugin is https://packagist.org/packages/finaldream/w3-total-cache that isn't official and also doesn't seem to be up-to-date (version `0.9.4.6` while w3tc is version `0.14.4`).

I can install it with the `wp-cli` in a machine in the final environment because it has the database, but it seems I can't install in a CI environment to create a docker image with pre-installed plugins, and I haven't found other questions and solutions about it.

**Is there a way to install the plugin in a CI environment, without a database?** (in the final environment, be it dev, staging, or production, I would only call `wp-cli` to activate the plugins, as I already do for plugins installed with composer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up considering that the best option in this case is to `curl` the zip file from wordpress (because in the end wordpress plugins are mainly directories inside the `plugins` folder).

I added the following instructions in the dockerfile:

```
ENV W3TC_VERSION 0.14.4

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/web/app/plugins \
 && curl -L https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/w3-total-cache.${W3TC_VERSION}.zip \
    -o /tmp/w3-total-cache.zip \
 && unzip /tmp/w3-total-cache.zip -d /var/www/html/web/app/plugins \
 && rm /tmp/w3-total-cache.zip \
 && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/web/app/plugins \
 && cp /var/www/html/web/app/plugins/w3-total-cache/wp-content/advanced-cache.php \
    /var/www/html/web/app/advanced-cache.php \
 && chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/web/app/advanced-cache.php \
 && mkdir -p /var/www/html/web/app/cache \
 && chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/web/app/cache \
 && mkdir -p /var/www/html/web/app/w3tc-config \
 && chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/web/app/w3tc-config
```

**Update (2020-08-20)**

I did as leymannx suggested in the comments and included a instruction in a post install instruction in the `composer.json` file to call a shell script with the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail

echo "$(date '+%F %X') Custom install - Start"

W3TC_VERSION=0.14.4
APP_DIR=/var/www/html/web/app
PLUGINS_DIR="$APP_DIR/plugins"
W3TC_URL="https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/w3-total-cache.${W3TC_VERSION}.zip"

if [ ! -d "$PLUGINS_DIR/w3-total-cache" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$PLUGINS_DIR"

    curl -L "$W3TC_URL" -o /tmp/w3-total-cache.zip

    unzip /tmp/w3-total-cache.zip -d "$PLUGINS_DIR"
    rm /tmp/w3-total-cache.zip

    chown -R www-data:www-data "$PLUGINS_DIR"

    cp "$PLUGINS_DIR"/w3-total-cache/wp-content/advanced-cache.php \
        "$APP_DIR"/advanced-cache.php
    chown www-data:www-data "$APP_DIR"/advanced-cache.php

    mkdir -p "$APP_DIR"/cache
    chown www-data:www-data "$APP_DIR"/cache

    mkdir -p "$APP_DIR"/w3tc-config
    chown www-data:www-data "$APP_DIR"/w3tc-config
fi

echo "$(date '+%F %X') Custom install - End"
```

*(I also removed those commands from the `Dockerfile`)*

This allowed to make the whole process more transparent for whoever uses this wordpress environment.

Comment: Can't you somehow grab some repo directly with Composer? I mean you manage your project with Composer already. Otherwise maybe put this as some post install command in the composer.json? It's just: How are your colleagues who git clone the project for the first time to know about this module and how to download it?

Comment: But which repo we would use with composer? The one I mentioned in the question seems outdated and is not official, and is the only one I found. The downloaded plugin, on the other hand, is official. In development we would use the same docker image, but because we would map the Wordpress folder to our repository this would make the plugin inaccessible, so I'm thinking about copying the `w3tc` plugin folder in the docker image (after all, it's just the plugin folder that is downloaded) to the `plugins` folders in the machine in a setup script.

Comment: That said, I will give a look at including it in a post install command in `composer.json` to make the whole process more straightforward.